# Unable to run php script in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with these php packages installed:
php5, php5-cli and php5-common

The version of php installed is

```
$ php -v  
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 16:53:10)  Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

When I download and run the script

> https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php

using

> php AdobeHDS.php --help

I expect to get help on command line switches allowed by the AdobeHDS.php command.

Instead, what I see is html output which is same as contents of the script.

```
$ php AdobeHDS.php --help > out.html 
$ diff AdobeHDS.php out.html 
$
```

As per
http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/342430-F4F-capturing-converting/page2
the script should recognize the --help switch.

Using any other switch like --manifest  also produces 
similar behavior.

I need help on how to run this script successfully.

Comment: `md5sum AdobeHDS.php` ? Must be `81751f2c5184f33a539b5e0bdfdf7adc`

Comment: @user3477071 How You've downloaded the script? with wget ?

Comment: can You try: wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/K-S-V/Scripts/master/AdobeHDS.php    and then try to run with php ?

Comment: I had downloaded the script as a html file. What I was running was not a php script but a html file. That explains why I got the same output as what I was running. I've downloaded the correct link as a text file and the script works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best guess, you downloaded the actual HTML file at https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php , because diff could not find any differences, it means PHP could not find any `<?php` tag to execute. (the only exception to this would be if the source was a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) )

the correct way to download your script:

`wget https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/raw/master/AdobeHDS.php`

notice how it has a /raw/ in the url :) it will download this https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/raw/master/AdobeHDS.php

also, the HTML code at github, does not actually contain any `<?php` , it just looks that way when parsed by your web browser, in reality, it's encoded by github as `&lt;?php` , per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2629

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am now able to run my script successfully.